# Crontab Wget not working

Tags: macos, terminal, cron, wget

I have a cron job set up on my Mac to download a file every hour using wget. The command is as follows:

```
0 * * * * wget -O "/Users/me/Downloads/example.txt" "http://www.example.com/example.txt"
```

This works absolutely fine when I run it in Terminal manually, but doesn't seem to be executing in Crontab when all other commands are.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting stdout/stderr?

Comment: Are there any percent (`%`) signs in the actual URL?

Comment: Nope, no percent signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't get wget to work, but accomplished same result by using:

```
0 * * * * curl -o "/Users/me/Downloads/example.txt" "http://www.example.com/example.txt"
```

Note the lowercase 'o' opposed to wget's uppercase 'O'

Comment: I also struggled a lot with wget. I believed the problem was my Mac machine and settings with the cron service. I also have to change here, but what if the server only has wget... ?